# Postgres TIME vs TIME with Time zone

Tags: django, postgresql, timezone

Could someone please explain the logic that Postgres applies when dealing with the following situation.

A Django view receives a string representation of time in the following format:

```
18:30 PM
```

which it then persisted to Postgres.  I created the 2 columns in the DB to highlight the difference in handling the above time:

```
start_at time NOT NULL,
start_at_tz timetz NOT NULL,
```

Here's what get saved in DB:

[image]

The behavior seems to be that some 7 hr difference that was applied to the timezone column. The value format doesn't seem to incorporate the 24 hr/day cutoff.

Earlier times get converted into:

13:00 PM

[image]

14:00 PM

[image]

Can someone please shed some light on the PostgreSQL bevahior.  I'm on an EST time zone, if that' relevant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Like the documentation says, `time with time zone` is there because the standard says so, but it is broken by concept. Don't use it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: would you mind elaborating a bit?

Comment: Done in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the database session that inserts the values is running with a different value of `timezone` than the session that you use to display the values.

`time with time zone` is interpreted in the session time zone for the current day and stored as time since midnight UTC.

You shouldn't use `time with time zone`, like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) says:

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness. In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without time zone`, and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete range of date/time functionality required by any application.

A time zone only makes sense in combination with a date, because there are time zones where the offset changes during the year. If you are in such a time zone, the displayed values for `time with time zone` will vary through the year.